# how to create bucket inside a buckets in aws-s3 using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have one s3-bucket with name "my-bucket".

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets.create('my-bucket')
```

bucket object has the reference to 'my-bucket'. how to create a another bucket inside it?

Comment: you can't create buckets inside of buckets

Comment: how to achieve the directory structure

Comment: you create objects with "/" in the name. These are automatically converted into "directories" by the Web Console and other S3 browsers.

Comment: a bucket holds folder not bucket. and ultimately a folder is also a bucket conceptually

Comment: You can not create new bucket inside existing bucket. But may add new folder in existing bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create buckets inside buckets - see the third paragraph on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html which states:

```
You cannot create a bucket within another bucket.
```

S3 is not a folder based storage, but rather more like a key value store. Buckets are, according to Amazon's docs, analogous to domain names.

You can simulate a folder structure by storing your files with their full path as the object name.

Answer (score 2):

Buckets hold neither other buckets nor folders. Object (file) key names delimited with "/" create a pseudo folder structure for organizational purposes, but it's really a single-level store. You have the bucket, and you have infinite items inside that bucket.